# Nodejs use of static route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my project I have a structure:

```
-- Development
---allure
----allure-report
-----index.html
---testcafe (running app folder)
----routes
-----test.js
----views
-----report.ejs
----package.json
----app.js
```

Now I want to show the index.html in my browser. For this I use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__basedir , '../allure/allure-report/')))
```

This will create the path to the "/development/allure/allure-report/" folder.

Now I use in the report.ejs Template:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
   <iframe src="index.html" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
</div>
```

But this will make a 404 error. In my idea this will render the index.html. This do not work. Is this a wrong way?

Comment: What URL is `index.html` relative *to*? i.e. what URL causes Express to use the report.ejs template in the first place?

Comment: Maybe you can try this one: `app.use(express.static('allure-report'))`.

Comment: `create the path`? I don't think so. This is not going to create directories on your disk. What does `console.log(thePath)` do? does the resolved path actually exist beforehand? Also, try `path.resolve(__dirname , '../allure/allure-report/')`